# Oracle- GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES?

Tags: oracle

Whenever I give a user "all privileges" in ORACLE (example below), what does this actually do?

My understanding is that it gives a user any privilege, e.g inserting, deleting etc *within that schema* but **not** to any schema in the DB?

```
grant all privileges to my_user;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `grant all [privileges] on <some object>`, but you aren't specifying an object; so you are granting system privileges:

> [image: grant_system_privileges]

The [documentation for system privileges](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#i2062318) says:

> Oracle Database provides the ALL PRIVILEGES shortcut for granting all the system privileges listed in [Table 18-1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#BABEFFEE), except the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY, ALTER DATABASE LINK, and ALTER PUBLIC DATABASE LINK privileges.

System privileges are not always restricted to a schema. That table includes a lot of `ANY` privileges, which are specifically *not* restricted to a schema. If you `grant all privileges` to a user they will be able to create or alter a table in any schema, for example. That probably isn't what you want.

There is no shortcut to grant only schema-restricted privileges. You'll need to grant `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE INDEX`, etc. explicitly.

It's common practice to [create a role](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/authorization.htm#BABCADIB) to which you grant the necessary privileges, and then you just have to grant that role to your users. (Although you sometimes still need to grant privileges directly to users, e.g. if they are required in a stored procedure).

Comment: ok thanks, can you give an example of how  I can remove the "ALL" privilege and re-assign only the roles that I need?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can `revoke all privileges from my_user`. The docs I linked to show how to create a role and assign privileges to it via `grant`. I can't tell you which roles or privs you need though.